# Scripting/object model/other interface to a .Net app

Tags: .net, com

I'm developing a .Net application that is used for scientific instrument control via a serial port. There is a requirement to allow users to "script" certain actions, e.g. open a valve, wait X seconds, send xyz data to the instrument, etc, etc. There are going to be dozens of different actions to choose from, plus logic/program flow (if statements, gotos, etc, etc).

The previous incarnation of the software used a basic UI where the user chooses from a list of possible actions to gradually build up a sequence of commands to run. It worked, and is great for non-programmers, but not particularly flexible. And if an error occurred, it wasn't easy to report the exact problem, or where in the script it occurred.

For the rewrite I'm trying to come up with a better solution, such as using a "real" scripting language. Program flow/logic is obviously part of the language itself, so I only have to concern myself with exposing/handling the different instrument actions. A scripting language would also provide better runtime errors, while intellisense would be a bonus.

My first thought was to expose my .Net "action" classes as some kind of COM object model, allowing more choice of scripting languages (VBScript, Python, Javascript?), but I'm a bit reluctant to go down the COM route as it's old technology (and tbh a bit of a black art which I've managed to avoid in all my years as a developer). There are no requirements around which languages should be supported, so C# and VB.Net are options also.

I'm really just looking for some ideas/pointers on how I could achieve scripting in my app. The script editor doesn't have to be integrated into the app, although that would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* do it with COM by exponsing a sensible object model. The benefit of this is that it would be fairly easy to use VBScript for scripting, or C++ for automation.

However, I am not sure if it is the best approach in terms of required effort. You could consider following options:

- Expose .NET model and script it with IronPython or Boo (if you prefer static typing). IronPython is great for this.
- Expose .NET model and script it with C#.

The latter is what I have chosen for my last application where I needed such functionality and in a addition it was supposed to be scriptable directly from the app itself. The driver for the decision to use C# was that we wanted to provide static typing and good intellisense, as the target users for scripting were our testers, who found it much easier to work that way, as the API was more discoverable and we could compile the scripts on-fly to provide at least some sanity check with regard to script contents.

The application exposed a .NET scripting model, while the editor and intellisense features were implemented by components from the SharpDevelop project. This made it possible to implement scripting support with syntax highlighting editor and intellisense within one day.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Having thought about it since posting my Q, I've also come to the same conclusion that C# is probably a better fit for what we are trying to do.